# Binding outgoing socket to specific (virtual) adapter

Tags: python, linux, sockets

Is it possible to bind a socket to a specific *virtual* adapter? 
Following Python code works fine for real adapters, eg. eth0 for cable, wlan0 for wifi:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, b"eth0")
```

But when I try to bind the socket to a virtual adapter e.g. "eth0:0" I get error "OSError: [Errno 19] No such device".

My virtual adapters seem to be working fine otherwise and can be pinged OK.

Basically, what I am trying to do is generate outgoing traffic from a specific ip (assigned to a virtual adapter). The intention is to load/flood test an embedded device on the network using a single computer.

Comment: you said you get error in bind, where is the bind code ?
usually you bind using a host which the ipaddress and a port number you dont need the interface name or index for example
`s.bind('10.10.10.10', 3003)`

Comment: @cmidi, my problem is with outgoing connections, not accepting incoming. Error is thrown when setting the socket option. Hope this makes it clearer:

's = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)'
's.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, adapter)'
's.connect((ADDRESS, PORT))'
's.send(msg)'

Answer (score 0):

You should know that for kernel these (eth0 and eth0:1) are the same interface eth0. 
Label or 'alias', like eth0:1 (actually you can use some better user-friendly label, like eth0:internal_net) is needed only for sysadmin,not for app
So you should rely on source IP (or let kernel select it automatically, according to routing table)